# Trivial Set Theory Proofs

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Unfortunately, I am not quite acquainted with the art of proving, so I will be grateful for any response to the following.

Let the $X$ and $Y$ be sets and let $f$ be function such that $f: X\to Y$. Prove:

1. $f^{-1}(f(V)) = V$ for all $V\subseteq X$ when $f$ is injective.
2. $f(f^{-1}(W)) = W$ for all $W\subseteq Y$ when $f$ is surjective.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to do double inclusions, e.g. for 1., prove that $f^{-1}(f(V))\subset V$ and $V \subset f^{-1}(f(V))$. For the first inclusion, take $x \in f^{-1}(f(V))$, then $f(x) \in f(V)$ and by injectivity of $f$, $x\in V$.

Can you take it from there for the other inclusions ?

Comment: I would love to say yes, but I am still struggling. Could you please explain the step x∈f−1(f(V)), then f(x)∈f(V) ?

Comment: That's by definition of the inverse image. For $B \subset Y$, $f^{-1}(B)=\{x \in X \ \vert \ f(x) \in B\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Start by proving that the statements $V\subseteq f^{-1}(f(V)$ for each $V\subseteq X$ and $f(f^{-1}(W))\subseteq W$ for each $W\subseteq Y$ are true in general. Injectivity and/or surjectivity of $f$ is not needed for this part.

For $v\in V$ we have $f(v)\in f(V)$ wich is exactly the same statement as $v\in f^{-1}(f(V))$.

If $y\in f(f^{-1}(W))$ then $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in f^{-1}(W)$, so that $y=f(x)\in W$.

---

Then it remains to be proved that:

1) $f^{-1}(f(V)\subseteq V$ for all $V\subseteq X$ if $f$ is injective.

2) $W\subseteq f(f^{-1}(W))$ for all $W\subseteq Y$ if $f$ is surjective.

Proof of 1): Let $V\subseteq X$ and $x\in f^{-1}(f(V)$. Then $f(x)\in f(V)$, so $f(x)=f(v)$ for some $v\in V$. Then injectivity of $f$ tells us that $x=v\in V$.

Proof of 2): Let $w\in W\subseteq Y$. The surjectivity of $f$ implies the existence of some $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=w\in W$. Then $x\in f^{-1}(W)$ and $w=f(x)\in f(f^{-1}(W))$.